# i need to get the total amount of guesses and also the total amount of games played for the guessing game

Tags: java

so this my first time coding and i need a lot of help trying to figure out to get the total amount of guesses and the total amount games played, i dont even know where to start. I can get the code to tell me how many guesses it took to get to the number in one game but not the overall result. Any tips or help?

thank you

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class treehouseproject {

   //Instruction on how to play the game
   public static void instruction() {
      System.out.println("this is a guessing game");
      System.out.println("you will guess the number");
      System.out.println("that i am thinking of");
      System.out.println("unitl you guess the correct number");
      System.out.println("the number ranges from 0 to 100");
   
   }


   //playing a single game
   public static void playgame() {
      int guessNumber = 0;
      int numberGuesses = 0;
      int plays = 0;
      int max = 100;
      int min = 0;
      Random randomNum = new Random();
      int givenNumber = min + randomNum.nextInt(max);
      
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
      
      while(guessNumber != givenNumber){
         numberGuesses++;
         System.out.println("Guess: " + numberGuesses);
         guessNumber = scan.nextInt();
         if (guessNumber == givenNumber) {
            System.out.println("correct");
            System.out.println("you go it right in " + numberGuesses + " guesses");
         }
      
         if (guessNumber < givenNumber) {
            System.out.println("higher");
         }
         if (guessNumber > givenNumber){
            System.out.println("lower");
         }
      
      
      }
   }
   
   
   



   //playing muliple games and reporting all end stats

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String Answer = "";
      instruction();
      playgame();
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("do you want to play again?");
      Answer = console.nextLine();
      boolean keep_playing = true;
      while (Answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
         playgame();
         System.out.println("do you want to play again?");
         Answer = console.nextLine();
      }
          
         
          
          
   }



//prints out the stats of the game

public static void results(int plays, int numberGuesses) {
   System.out.println("Overall results");
   System.out.println("Total amount of guesses = " + numberGuesses);
   System.out.println("Total amount of games = " + plays);
  
   }

         
}
```

Comment: Perhaps reset the counter after each game ends?

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are encountering actually has a pretty simple solution.
So if you define a variable it as a certain "lifespan" this means that is effectively dies at some point.
Every variable is only "alive" within the parents of its parent.
Example:

```
public static void main(string args[]){
    String s1 = "";
    private static void doSomething(){
         String s2 = s1;
    } 
}
```

The variable s1 is "alive" until the parenthesizes of its parent (main) close, so its also alive within the function and fully usable.
s2 on the other hand is only alive within "doSomething", so it cannot be referenced after its bracket closes.
So moving the initialization of variables to a more "global" level is often very usefull.

You need to move the initialization of the these variables outside of playGame() and to the global level.

- numberGuesses
- plays